# Excel Query : cell with -ve values symbol treated as calculation instead of text

Tags: excel, formula-editor

I copy pasted content from a webpage which includes 3 columns as specified below.

```
abc 10  30
def -20 -1.2
ghi -12 3
```

When I copy pasted data to a excel sheet as paste special values as text. The cell is treating 2nd and 3rd column as a formulae and provides result -21.2 (=-20-1.2). Ideally I want it to be total 3 different columns.

Any cell with -ve in the beginning is treated as a formulae in excel. How do I resolve ?

Comment: can you copy website url here (if it's not sensitive). *really* hard to reproduce.

Comment: It is internal to my company weblink. As I mentioned, there are 3 columns as specified above. I want to paste into excel as values but 2nd and 3rd column are getting merged as one calculation for 2nd and 3rd row. 1st row preserves 3 different columns as there is no -ve symbol in the begining.